# Log4net writing to C: instead of APPDATA on Windows 2003

Tags: c#, logging, iis-6, log4net, windows-2003-webserver

I have a .NET web application that should log stuff to the APPDATA environment variable with log4net. On my XP dev computer it works just fine, but when deployed to a Windows 2003 server the logs are written to C:\ instead. I've tried using both Network Service and my own user account (with admin rights) for running the IIS app pool and there's no difference.

The log4net appender config looks like this:

```
<appender name="RollingFile" type="log4net.Appender.RollingFileAppender">
  <file value="${APPDATA}\appname\log."/>
  <appendToFile value="true" />
  <rollingStyle value="Date" />
  <staticLogFileName value="false" />
  <datePattern value="'.'yyyy-MM-dd'.txt'" />
  <maxSizeRollBackups value="14" />
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date&#9;%-5level&#9;%message%newline" />
  </layout>
</appender>
```

I don't think there's a problem with write permissions, because it works if I change the config to this:

```
<file value="c:\Documents and Settings\username\Application Data\appname\log."/>
```

Anyone has any idea what's wrong and how to fix it?

Comment: got the same problem, and only happens on Win2003 server, should be a bug  of log4net

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The APPDATA requires a user profile to have been created.  This won't be the case for the Network Service account.  If you run the Application Pool under an explicit identity, I believe this identity will need to have logged in at least once to create the profile.

I suggest you don't rely on the existence of a user profile in web applications, and choose some other location for your log files.

Comment: That explains the Network Service then, but my own account has been logged in plenty and still no luck.

Comment: Could it be this, but also that the web application runs as ASPNET and NOT as the user of the application pool, and the ASPNET user has no profile?

Comment: Have you configured the APp pool to load the user profile? http://blogs.msdn.com/b/vijaysk/archive/2009/03/08/iis-7-tip-3-you-can-now-load-the-user-profile-of-the-application-pool-identity.aspx

Comment: It's on IIS6, so I can't. Seems I have to abandon the whole appdata-approach like you first suggested. Thanks!